# How to drive TRIAC from MCU with supply referenced to low-voltage AC "hot"?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, triac

I have a requirement to drive a triac from the MCU powered by a DC/DC converter. The AC supply is typ 24 VAC @ Rc terminal with respect to C terminal.  The triac is driven as follows. The MCU GND is always regulated at Rc -  3V3. The MCU output which drives the gate preferably will be connected straight, without the BJT. The gate current is II/III quadrants is typ 5 mA.

[image]

How can I configure the DC/DC converter and its input?

The problem is a real world design issue I am trying to solve. I can use an opto coupled triac driver to solve this. But this is a cost sensitive application, so I am trying to see if I can find a feasible solution without any isolation.

The triac drives a 24V A/C motor. When I tried the triac drive as MT1 connected to GND and MT2 to the load, I loose a feedback signal generated from the motor. I have no control over this, as this is inherent to the motor controller. So I have to wire-up the triac as MT1 to Rc (Live) and MT2 to the load. So instead of switching the 'C' (or neutral), I have to switch the 'Rc' (or Live). This is the constraint.

To further to reduce BoM cost, I am trying not to use any BJTs or FETs to drive the triac gate. To do this, and also for better switching, I want to operate the triac in II and III quadrants, where gate current is negative. I plan to use Z0103 as the triac and in II/III quadrants, I could trigger it @ -4mA (considering temperature range). My MCU (STM32F103) can sink/source 8mA from GPIO so this should be viable. This is my idea for the moment, I could be wrong.

This is where my initial design came from. I think this way might also be a viable solution.
[image]

We can configure a standard buck as a negative output regulator, so this way  the MCU GND will follow the Rc below 3V3.

The DC/DC Buck could be anything which can accept up to 60VDC and source at least 1A.

Comment: Is this homework? Is there a DC/DC converter you are required to use? Can you provide any manufacturer part numbers possible please?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Do you need to time something to the AC cycle in your MCU?

Comment: If your MCU needs less than 20 mA you can use a negative linear regulator like LT3015EMSE-3.3. A better solution is an isolated DC/DC converter where you can connect +VIN and +VOUT (RC in the circuit).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an acceptable method.

Note that:

- You generally want to drive with as much current as possible (given device ratings, thermal limits, driver capacity, etc.), to ensure rapid and complete turn-on.
- Gate is the base of some back-to-back transistors that make up the thyristor (effectively); as such, it has voltage drop (a V<sub>BE</sub>) while conducting, in the direction of load current.  So, I would put a diode or two in there, to introduce a little voltage drop, ensuring the MCU isn't reverse-biased while the load is reversed.
- Gate drive doesn't need to be maintained (continuous) while an on-state is desired, but it should be pulsed to ensure the TRIAC doesn't turn off due to unexpected load current phase (which, a motor will be notably inductive, with phase depending on torque).  A modest duty cycle (say, 10-20µs on-time, 10% duty) might help save 3V3 current consumption, say.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have prototyped it and seem to work. I have not yet tried full temp range yet, but I think that should be ok. Sorry for my delay in replying.